# Qlikview Set Analysis

Tags: set, analysis, dollar-sign, qlikview

I have to compare the sales in two different years in [qlikview](/questions/tagged/qlikview).

The set analysis done like the help suggest doesn't work

```
=sum( {$<ID_Ac_EDIZIONE_WI={$(=only(ID_Ac_EDIZIONE_WI)-1)}>} ORC_Mo_ImponibileRiga_Attuale)
```

it gives me a column of zeros;

modifing it like this

```
=sum( {1<ID_Ac_EDIZIONE_WI={$(=only(ID_Ac_EDIZIONE_WI)-1)}>} ORC_Mo_ImponibileRiga_Attuale)
```

it creates two different rows, each one per year.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please add more information, like some datasets. Then we can copy it an try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to diagnose without seeing your data model, or at least some sample data.  If you provide a few rows of sample data in an inline script it will be a lot easier for someone to help you.

The only suggestion I can make without seeing your data is to try wrapping the dollar expansion expression in single quotes:

For example, this:

```
=sum( {$<ID_Ac_EDIZIONE_WI={'$(=only(ID_Ac_EDIZIONE_WI)-1)'}>} ORC_Mo_ImponibileRiga_Attuale)
```

Instead of this:

```
=sum( {$<ID_Ac_EDIZIONE_WI={$(=only(ID_Ac_EDIZIONE_WI)-1)}>} ORC_Mo_ImponibileRiga_Attuale)
```

Comment: It might be helpful for others who stumble across this thread if you share the solution... :)